# request.financial() limit workaround (PineScript)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to get the full set of financial data on TradingView, we can get this type of data calling it like that: '`request.financial(syminfo.prefix+":"+syminfo.ticker, "accounts_payable", "FQ")`', anyway there is a limit number of calls for this function (40 calls).
Security calls had the same problem in previous versions of pinescript, but now you can get more data on a single request using arrays '`[o,h,l,c,h2,h3,h4] = security(syminfo.ticker, timeframe.period, [open,high,low,close,hl2,hlc3,ohlc4])`'.
The problem is that `request.financial()` does not accept array input, so, is there any other workaround of this type to get more than 40 financials?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no workaround for that as of now. `financials()` do not support tuples.